# Websocket method to handle Icecast Metadata?

Tags: php, python, node.js, iis, icecast

I run a public services scanner website that allows people to listen to police, fire, etc.   It streams via Icecast on Ubuntu from the backend, and I'm running the front-end website from Joomla on IIS/PHP.

I have a python script on the streaming server that parses information from the scanner radio's display, to grab the current frequency/talkgroup and applies this to the song title of the stream.  An AJAX request on the front-end website then queries the icecast server for the song title every 5 seconds, as this changes quite often.

Recently and event in the area caused an enormous amount of vistors to the site.  The constant queries to update the song title on the website crushed my internet connection, so I began to investigate other methods, and stumbled upon websockets.  My understanding is that rather than have the clients constantly request the song title, websockets would allow me to push only upon change.

I started to play with icecast-stack, an mpn module that is part of node.js.   While this seemed promising, I'm having a hard time grasping how to implement this.  It appears there is a complete icecast/html5/node.js player in the works, but hasn't yet been completed.

My second thought would be to use node.js to build a chat client/server.  This concept makes sense, as visitors would be a chat "client", as well as the icecast server itself, sending messages to a chat server.  Where I struggle with this is with my python script on the icecast server;  how do I send my variable within python to a node.js chat server?

If anyone has some sample code to share, or possibly another idea altogether, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks much!

Comment: If you're interested, I have code I can license to you which handles this completely client-side.  That is, it demuxes the ICY-style metadata without making separate connections to the server.  Contact me at brad@audiopump.co if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets are for bi-directional communication, which you don't need.  Use [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) instead.

On the client, you'll do something like this:

```
const metaEventSource = new EventSource('/metadata');
metaEventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
});
```

Server-side, there are many abstractions available depending on which stack you ultimately choose.  It's a simple text-base response format:

```
event: metadata
data: Your new metadata goes here
```